# Prefix taskbar icon with number

Tags: windows-7

The new Win+0..9 shortcut seems good, but it only seems useful for the first few apps in the taskbar. Is it possible to make Windows prefix the icon with a number 1 to 9 ?

Answer (score 12):

[7+ Taskbar Numberer](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-numberer)

[image: Screenshot]

> 7+ Taskbar Numberer adds numbers to your taskbar items, so you can see
>   right away what keyboard shortcut is assigned to each item.
>   Optionally, the numbers can appear only when the Windows key is down.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

I think it has already been asked on SuperUser. And it's also listed on Windows 7 Taskforce ([**here**](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/3500) for instance).