# Is it possible to show numbers for each app on the task bar?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I like the fact that I can launch apps on the task bar by using hot keys such as <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd>.

But, is it possible to show those numbers on the task bar?

Comment: Google gave me [this result](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-numberer), may fit the bill for you.  But it is a 3rd party program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefix taskbar icon with number](http://superuser.com/questions/94263/prefix-taskbar-icon-with-number). [Get numeric position indicator on icons in taskbar?](http://superuser.com/questions/303856/get-numeric-position-indicator-on-icons-in-taskbar), [Is there any way for Windows 7 taskbar to show the index of each app?](http://superuser.com/questions/197488/is-there-any-way-for-windows-7-taskbar-to-show-the-index-of-each-app), [Usage of Windows+Number combination on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/287770/usage-of-windowsnumber-combination-on-windows-7) etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this program *7+ Numberer*, is appropriate for your case.

[image]

> You can use the Windows key+number keyboard shortcut to refer to a
> taskbar item.
>
> Source: [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts).

*[Developer Reference](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-numberer)*.

Comment: @TiagoCA Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @nerdwaller I had this question on my mind for a very long time. I've searched it up years ago and couldn't find it. I didn't Google (Though I should have) because of that reason. My bad :)

Comment: @TimothyOnggowasito - No worries, I am sure that others will find this helpful as well, which is the goal of SU.